# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Docker is not setting a default nginx reverse proxy to application port

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've deployed a dockerized node app to elastic beanstalk and instead of my app, the link goes to a default "Welcome to nginx on Amazon Linux!" page saying it means the web server is installed at the site.

It's using Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2

From what I could find scouring the internet, the eb default nginx reverse proxy should forward to either port 8000, 8080, or 5000 (information varies).

I've confirmed my docker app is running properly and opened all three ports to the docker container as a test to narrow later. I know that part is working fine because allowing incoming for them in the ec2 security group successfully routes to my app using the ec2 public IP i.e. 55.555.555.555:8080 or 55.555.555.555:5000

Related answers suggest I can find the reverse proxy port in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk-nginx-docker-upstream.conf` (not found) or `/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf` (not found).

Here's `/etc/nginx/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can add my own nginx config in .ebextensions but I'm really trying to avoid it because I don't know what I'm doing, more to maintain, and shouldn't this just work out of the box?

Update:

I added

```
location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

to the nginx.conf server block within the ec2 container, restarted the service, and now the eb url correctly routes to my app.

How do I avoid having to do this for every environment or using a custom nginx config?

Comment: Are you using a `docker-compose.yml` file for production deployment?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2` should use `.platform` folder to customize your nginx as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) in "Reverse proxy configuration" section.

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```